# Get values multiple times from same tags

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I use SoapUI to handle SOAP requests. I try to match same regex multiple times on same SOAP response, it contains same tag, `<ns12:AmountID>`  multiple times and I need all the values. I use regex in `Groovy` script in this way:

```
String numberToGet = reger.getNthMatch(/<ns12:AmountID>(\d+)<\/ns12:AmountID>/, 0);
```

How could I differ output values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have this with below code which is easy to understand and deal with XML.

Also i feel the syntax is easy to remember compared to XMLSlurper. One of the best ways to retrieve value from any XML

```
def groovyUtils=new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

// Cosidering your soap request name is **SampleRequest**
def respsone=groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("SampleRequest#Response")

def AmountId=respsone.getNodeValues("//*:AmountID")

// Printing as a list
log.info AmountId.toString()

// Printing as individual item from Array
for(def var in AmountId)
log.info var
```

Below is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

XPath or Groovy's GPath are almost always a better way of finding things in XML documents than using regular expressions. For example:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def amountIDstring = '''
<root xmlns:ns12="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <ns12:AmountID>1230</ns12:AmountID>
    <ns12:AmountID>460</ns12:AmountID>
    <ns12:AmountID>123</ns12:AmountID>
    <ns12:AmountID>670</ns12:AmountID>
    <ns12:AmountID>75</ns12:AmountID>
    <ns12:AmountID>123</ns12:AmountID>
</root>
'''

def amountIDtext = new XmlSlurper().parseText(amountIDstring)
def numberToGet  = amountIDtext.'**'.findAll{node -> node.name() == 'AmountID'}*.text()

numberToGet.each{ println "Amount ID = ${it}"}
```

This returns:

```
Amount ID = 1230
Amount ID = 460
Amount ID = 123
Amount ID = 670
Amount ID = 75
Amount ID = 123
Result: [1230, 460, 123, 670, 75, 123]
```